# error in uploading image through jquery asp.net mvc 3.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to upload a single image to server. The project is using .NET MVC, jQuery and jQueryUi.
**error show :** *IO Error*
can you people help me about this error.

My code is given below:

**these directive i have include in my project.**

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js")"></script>
<link href="@Href("~/Content/uploadify.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Href("~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).load(
            function() {
                $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
                        'uploader': '/Scripts/uploader.swf',
                        'cancelImg': '/images/cancel.png',
                        'buttonText': 'Select Image',
                        'script': 'ShowClientQuotation/Upload',
                        'folder': '/images',
                        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                        'multi': false,
                        'auto': true
                    });
            }
);
```

**html:**

```
<div id="fileuploader"></div>
```

**My Controller Name**: *ShowClientQuotation*

```
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
        {
            var fileName = this.Server.MapPath("~/images/UserProfilePic/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
            fileData.SaveAs(fileName);

            return "ok";
        }
```

Comment: Does your Action get called by this? I think you will have to add the [httppost] attribute on top of your Upload action.

Comment: Does the "images" have write permission?

Comment: And why do you attach this handler on the window's on load event and not the document.ready event?

Comment: @Rob Angelier: b/c i have a sample project, in which they use windows.load

Comment: if you want to see the sample code online from where i download this code:
http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Upload-Files-In-RAZOR-With-jQuery-Uploadify-Plugin.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only changes in JS Code:

```
$(window).load(
            function() {
                $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
                        'uploader': '/Scripts/uploader.swf',
                        'cancelImg': '/images/cancel.png',
                        'buttonText': 'Select Image',
                        'script': "@Url.Action("ShowClientQuotation", "upload")",
                        'folder': '/images',
                        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                        'multi': false,
                        'auto': true
                    });
            }
);
```

after changes, my code runs perfectly. 
thank you for all.